# How lenient are conferences in accepting and reviewing lately submitted poster presentation abstracts?

Tags: conference, peer-review, abstract, poster, deadlines

There is a conference that my advisor suggested that I attend and present at, but unfortunately as this was just suggested today, I missed the abstract submission deadline by about a week.

I know this is my fault, but I am just wondering how lenient conferences are wrt late registration. I emailed the organizer politely explaining the situation and asking if it would still be possible to register. If anyone is curious, this is for the SIAM annual meeting in Chicago.

I've never attended any sort of conference at this level before (but do have some experience with poster presentations), so I'm wondering should I even expect a reply, let alone a positive one? I think this would be a really great opportunity for me to present my research to people in the field, and I will most likely attend the conference even if I'm not able to present at the poster session.

---

**Edit and update:** The organizing committee has agreed to give consideration to my abstract, and said they'd let me know by the end of next week re: acceptance/rejection.

Comment: I would expect a large, formally organized meeting like this one to have no leniency.  Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

Some conferences usually/always extend. Others don't. I suggest writing to the organisers and asking - the worst that can happen is that they say no, and they might say yes, even if an extension hasn't been formally announced!

Answer (score 5):

Some conferences (I don't know if it applies for the one you have in mind as well) give the opportunity for the submission of so-called "late breaking posters" even after the official submission deadline until shortly before the conference date.

By this one can present very recent results that did not get ready before the deadline. As a drawback it should be noted that the contribution will normally not be listed in the conference proceedings as they will already go into preparation/production soon after the deadline. Also the reviewers might have a special eye on the originality and the currency of the contribution, so submitting some rather well hung stuff just to get a poster presentation and a reason to attend the conference might not work.

Comment: I did miss the breaking posters deadline by about a week. But the conference director let me send her an abstract, which she forwarded to the co-chairs, who ultimately have the final say. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

Most would not let you submit your abstract. However - I would guess that it  depends on the size of the conference, the amount of submissions, and the committee members themselves.

It doesn't hurt to ask!